# Scaling up random guess benchmark of log loss

Tags: classification, loss-functions, log-loss

[On Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-I-have-a-classification-algorithm-binary-with-a-logloss-of-0-69-does-this-mean-my-algorithm-is-no-better-than-a-random-guess) it's said that for a random guess log loss is equal to ln(0.5) = ~0.693

> That indeed implies that with a log loss of 0.69, you aren't doing any
>   better than a random guess.

OK, great. But I assume this is only true for a binary dependent variable, correct? So, if we're talking about multi-class log loss with something like 5 classes in the dependent variable, what log loss value is the random guess benchmark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your prediction is uniformly random, the expected value of the estimated probability of each class is $E\left[p_{i,j}\right]=K^{-1}$, where $K$ is the number of classes. The random guess benchmark is:

$$S(K)=-\log{K^{-1}}=\log{K}$$

If $K=5$

$$S(K=5)=\log{5}=1.609$$